# ZendFramework 2 - Error in loading layout for different modules

Tags: layout, module, zend-framework2

In `./config/application.config.php`

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Admin',
    )
    ...
```

I have 2 separate set of layouts, `./module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml` and `./module/Admin/view/layout/layout.phtml`

In `./module/Admin/config/module.config.php`

```
...
'template_map' => array(
    'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
    'header'        => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/header.phtml',
    'footer'        => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/footer.phtml',
    'paginator'     => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/paginator.phtml',
    'error/404'     => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
    'error/index'   => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
)
...
```

In `./module/Application/config/module.config.php`

```
...
'template_map' => array(
    'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
    'header'        => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/header.phtml',
    'footer'        => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/footer.phtml',
    'paginator'     => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/paginator.phtml',
    'error/404'     => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
    'error/index'   => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
)
...
```

Basically they are different set and some of the content are different. Unfortunately, both module only load the layout located in In `./module/Admin/config/module.config.php`

I googled but didn't fount any solution that I want. Anyone has any idea on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be interested to know, what your configuration actually does. [My Blog Post about this Topic](http://samminds.com/2013/04/understanding-zf2-configuration/), may interest you. Ultimately all Configuration files will be merged to one. The global configuration keys are **not** on a per-module basis ;)

To achieve your goal you should read [Evan Courys Blog Post "Module-specific layouts in ZF2"](http://blog.evan.pro/module-specific-layouts-in-zend-framework-2)

Evan provides [a Module "EdpModuleLayouts"](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts) that makes things pretty easy. If however you only need one alternative Layout for your AdminModule, then i suggest you simply go with the example code of his Blog Post to set an alternate Layout for your AdminModule directy via your `AdminModule/Module::onBootstrap`

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
            $controller      = $e->getTarget();
            $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
            $moduleNamespace = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));
            if ('AdminModule' === $moduleNamespace ) {
                $controller->layout('layout/admin');
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Not that this will set the layout to `layout/admin`. You would need to provide this key via your configuration:

```
'template_map' => array(
    'layout/admin' => 'path/to/admin/module/view/layout/admin.phtml',
)
```

Comment: In ZF 2.2.2, I had to replace the $moduleNamespace variable, then it worked for me: `if ('Admin' === $moduleNamespace ) { $controller->layout('layout/admin'); }`